# How can I resolve the following Plaid API error: "Internal Error Occurred"?

Tags: ruby, api, plaid

I'm trying to create a ruby script to download transactions from my bank account using the Plaid API.  I'm using the example app.rb script provided from the plaid GitHub site.  When I run the script, it starts a Sinatra server so I can select and enter my bank account's login credentials.  After adding the 'correct' creds, the web page says *"Internal Error has Occurred - We have been notified of the problem"*

My suspicion is that my script edits are wrong.  Does anyone have experience with this?

Here is the portion of the script code getting hit:

```
1 require 'base64'
2 require 'date'
3 require 'json'
4 require 'plaid'
5 require 'sinatra'
6 
7 set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/static'
8 
9 client = Plaid::Client.new(env: 'development',#ENV['PLAID_ENV'],
10.client_id: 'myClientIDHere',#ENV['PLAID_CLIENT_ID'],
11 secret: 'mySecretHere',#ENV['PLAID_SECRET'],
12 public_key: 'myPublicKeyHere)#ENV['PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY'])
13 access_token = nil
14 
15 get '/' do
16   erb :index
17 end
18 
19 # Exchange token flow - exchange a Link public_token for
20 # an API access_token
21 # https://plaid.com/docs/#exchange-token-flow
22 post '/get_access_token' do
23   exchange_token_response =
24     client.item.public_token.exchange(params['public_token'])
25   access_token = exchange_token_response['access_token']
26   pretty_print_response(exchange_token_response)
27 
28   content_type :json
29   exchange_token_response.to_json
30 end
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.  The web page that displays the internal error Error, has a response which indicates that my client_id has used too many requests in the 'development' server.  Changing 'development' to 'sandbox' on line 9 fixed the problem for me.

Comment: could you clarify: are you saying you were able to retrieve an access_token for your own bank account in Sandbox, after being throttled in dev? As I understood it, sandbox contains only mock data, and can't be used to retrieve anything from a real institution.